# How to get $E[Y_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]-Y_n=(2b-6)n+b+c-5 ? $

Tags: probability, analysis, stochastic-processes

Let $S_n$ be a symmetric simple random walk starting at $0$, and $Y_n=S_n^4-6nS_n^2+bn^2+cn$. How to get
$$
E[Y_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]-Y_n=(2b-6)n+b+c-5 ?
$$

---

It seems the computation is so hard since
$$
E[Y_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]-Y_n=E[S_{n+1}^4-6(n+1)S_{n+1}^2+b(n+1)^2+c(n+1)|\mathcal{F}_n]-(S_n^4-6nS_n^2+bn^2+cn)
$$

Comment: You should define your notation. For example, what is $\mathcal{F}_n$. Is $\mathcal{F}_n =\sigma(S_1, S_2,\ldots, S_n)$ ? Is $S_0=0$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply because $Z_n=S_n^4-6nS_n^2+6n^2$ is a martingale, which can be verified by noting that $(\partial_t+\mathcal{L})(x^4-6tx^2+6t^2)=0$ where $\mathcal{L}$ is the infinitesimal operator of the SSRW(it is a difference operator, but it works well just by taking $\mathcal{L}=\frac 12\partial_x^2$ as SSRW is similar to Brownian motion). Thus $E[Z_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_n]=Z_n$ and the desired equality follows.

Then it seems like your equality is kind of incorrect...